# Using the inspect tool on a component with a percentage value in a style, crashes the simulator

Tags: react-native

I see that percentage values in styles [are now](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f49e743bea730907066677c7cbfbb1260677d11) supported in ReactNative. I am have started working on a project that uses `react-native v0.55.4`, with percentages in its styles. However, when I bring up the debug tools, click "inspect" and click on a component that uses a percentage I get the following error:

```
JSON value '6.4%; of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber
```

This also causes an equivalent error when using values like `auto` for width.

I've been trying to work out how fix this, but I can't work out where I need to put the fix. Does anyone have any ideas?

Note: I'm using iOS Simulator v10

Comment: Can you add the code where you get the error, maybe where the value is `6.4%`?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: No, still occurs